# Spark Streaming - batch in waiting state, app doing nothing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What does the `waiting batches` in the Spark Streaming UI mean? I got a custom network receiver started and in the stats I can see following:

```
Time since start: 25 minutes 42 seconds
Network receivers: 2
Batch interval: 1 second 
Processed batches: 0
Waiting batches: 1
Received records: 0
Processed records: 0
```

And the receiver is doing nothing. It is still waiting "for something" What is the real state of the app. What is going on inside? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your spark is actually doing something (perhaps it takes a long time?), since waiting batches are the ones that are actually being processed - [see this](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201504.mbox/%3CCALte62yRy40ws13f+qf3mCfLifkxO_rdcmOurkg3B2EF3+XDRw@mail.gmail.com%3E).